# Using asset-pipeline in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How do I go about configuring my application to use the asset pipeline in Rails 3.0?
Pointers to any blogs/tutorials would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assets pipeline was introduced in Rails 3.1, maybe it would be easier to migrate to 3.1 and and use it as is?

Comment: That would involve migration of a huge application. Not really an option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asset pipeline is effectively sprockets, so for Rails 3.0:

https://gist.github.com/980056

Comment: Thanks! Pretty much what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/jamesmacaulay/sprockets_rails3_backport - exactly what you need.

Comment: I got this to work, but I cannot get it to NOT compile assets (for debugging in development environment). I've tried setting `config.assets.debug = true` and `config.assets.compile = false` in the /config/environments/development.rb file, but it still compiles all js files into the application.js on GET request. Any help with this?