# Rails loads css files from public/stylesheet instead of app/assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.0 and I  want to load  CSS stylesheet file form public/stylesheet.

Comment: why not just copy your stylesheets into app/assets?

Comment: I believe it won't work as he is working with 3.0.0 and asset pipelining was introduced in later versions. try including the stylesheet in layout using "stylesheet_link_tag".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986312/using-asset-pipeline-in-rails-3-0

Answer (score 1):

For versions greater that 3.0.0 go to **app/views/layouts/application.html.[erb/haml or whatever]** and add the line

`= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'`

under your head tag. This way you can link your page to the stylesheet at **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**. You can choose your desired file name instead of "application". But for versions upto 3.0.0(included) the above code will link the css file at **public/stylesheets/application.css**. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878765/css-in-rails-3-0)